# Why do I hear a beep on this program?

Tags: c++

I saw this `char szPrivateKey[]` definition on a source when I was reading so I went to check it out what it was, strangely this makes a sound when the program is run. Is there an easter egg in here or something? (compiled using visual studio 2003/ windows)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const unsigned char szPrivateKey[] = {
    0x30 ,0x82 ,0x04 ,0xBB ,0x02 ,0x01 ,0x00 ,0x30 ,0x0D ,0x06 ,0x09 ,0x2A ,0x86 ,0x48 ,0x86 ,0xF7 ,
    0x0D ,0x01 ,0x01 ,0x01 ,0x05 ,0x00 ,0x04 ,0x82 ,0x04 ,0xA5 ,0x30 ,0x82 ,0x04 ,0xA1 ,0x02 ,0x01 ,
    0x00 ,0x02 ,0x82 ,0x01 ,0x01 ,0x00 ,0x87 ,0x1F ,0xEC ,0xFD ,0xAF ,0xD2 ,0x2F ,0xAA ,0x4E ,0xC2 ,
    0xAD ,0x5A ,0x4C ,0x3A ,0x7A ,0x81 ,0x9E ,0xBA ,0x28 ,0x6A ,0x84 ,0xE9 ,0xB7 ,0xF9 ,0x36 ,0x87 ,
    0x56 ,0x16 ,0xC5 ,0xA4 ,0x1D ,0x11 ,0x67 ,0x12 ,0x87 ,0x81 ,0xF5 ,0xFA ,0xF6 ,0x01 ,0xE7 ,0x55 ,
    0x83 ,0x4A ,0xAC ,0x40 ,0x4D ,0x2C ,0x90 ,0x62 ,0x77 ,0xFC ,0x73 ,0xF9 ,0x5E ,0x7F ,0x67 ,0x8C ,
    0xA7 ,0x94 ,0x32 ,0x28 ,0xDD ,0xEF ,0x91 ,0xE5 ,0x94 ,0xD6 ,0x5C ,0xB5 ,0x63 ,0xC4 ,0x76 ,0x2D ,
    0xFF ,0x03 ,0x75 ,0x55 ,0x85 ,0x60 ,0x56 ,0x44 ,0x37 ,0x18 ,0x08 ,0xE7 ,0x0A ,0x90 ,0x74 ,0xA0 ,
    0x9E ,0x82 ,0x4F ,0x56 ,0x4C ,0xD9 ,0xE5 ,0x73 ,0x88 ,0x9E ,0x0F ,0xD2 ,0x0C ,0x9E ,0xF1 ,0x90 ,
    0x65 ,0xEF ,0xA4 ,0x23 ,0x99 ,0xCC ,0xE8 ,0x16 ,0xF7 ,0x96 ,0x54 ,0xDA ,0xF0 ,0x45 ,0x66 ,0x48 ,
    0xFE ,0xE6 ,0x89 ,0xA9 ,0xFC ,0x57 ,0xA5 ,0xD0 ,0xEC ,0x48 ,0x61 ,0xC7 ,0x7B ,0x8E ,0xC9 ,0x26 ,
    0x39 ,0xB3 ,0x8D ,0x64 ,0x89 ,0xAB ,0x4E ,0xF5 ,0xCD ,0x5A ,0x72 ,0xC5 ,0xEE ,0x2F ,0x73 ,0x34 ,
    0x9E ,0x0F ,0xA4 ,0x2E ,0x54 ,0x6D ,0x09 ,0x3B ,0x14 ,0x37 ,0x6C ,0x82 ,0x75 ,0x75 ,0xE0 ,0x80 ,
    0x5D ,0xB9 ,0xA8 ,0xFC ,0x5F ,0xE6 ,0x8F ,0x9D ,0x23 ,0x1C ,0x4B ,0xDA ,0xC1 ,0xB2 ,0x52 ,0x83 ,
    0xEA ,0xF6 ,0xE9 ,0x30 ,0x47 ,0x22 ,0x8C ,0x7E ,0x74 ,0x98 ,0x82 ,0x05 ,0x0B ,0x39 ,0xBD ,0x47 ,
    0x38 ,0x6B ,0xAE ,0x5F ,0xD4 ,0x21 ,0x0F ,0xE1 ,0xBA ,0x86 ,0x50 ,0x01 ,0x40 ,0x22 ,0x90 ,0xE0 ,
    0xE4 ,0xC4 ,0x11 ,0x50 ,0xA6 ,0x02 ,0x2F ,0x6C ,0x66 ,0xFC ,0xBE ,0x4B ,0x29 ,0xB0 ,0x0D ,0xE1 ,
    0x65 ,0x87 ,0xFE ,0x8B ,0x88 ,0x59 ,0x8D ,0x22 ,0xFC ,0x67 ,0xE2 ,0xE3 ,0x96 ,0x99 ,0xE5 ,0xAB ,
    0x2F ,0xA4 ,0x15 ,0x22 ,0x37 ,0x57 ,0x02 ,0x01 ,0x11 ,0x02 ,0x82 ,0x01 ,0x00 ,0x0B ,0xEC ,0x3A ,
    0x8E ,0xDA ,0xCE ,0xC7 ,0xF8 ,0x70 ,0x5C ,0x78 ,0xB5 ,0x24 ,0xD7 ,0xFB ,0xC0 ,0x24 ,0x97 ,0xF4 ,
    0x81 ,0xDE ,0x8D ,0x17 ,0xC3 ,0x2A ,0x75 ,0x5A ,0x6B ,0x6B ,0xCA ,0xB7 ,0x45 ,0x4C ,0xDB ,0xFC ,
    0xE5 ,0xD1 ,0xF0 ,0x7F ,0x1E ,0x49 ,0x1E ,0x22 ,0x2C ,0x3C ,0x60 ,0x06 ,0xCF ,0x39 ,0xEA ,0x92 ,
    0x1D ,0xCD ,0xFF ,0x6A ,0x38 ,0x6B ,0x04 ,0xE1 ,0x9C ,0x22 ,0x8B ,0x22 ,0xA4 ,0x32 ,0x85 ,0x32 ,
    0xC7 ,0x9E ,0xC4 ,0xB5 ,0xFA ,0xBF ,0x22 ,0x2D ,0x16 ,0xE4 ,0xB4 ,0xB8 ,0xF1 ,0xE9 ,0x7E ,0x7D ,
    0x54 ,0xF1 ,0xBA ,0x08 ,0x76 ,0x28 ,0x68 ,0x86 ,0x74 ,0xE8 ,0xE1 ,0xF7 ,0xB8 ,0xDF ,0x8A ,0x31 ,
    0xB3 ,0x97 ,0xFB ,0xF2 ,0x0E ,0x06 ,0x41 ,0x72 ,0x67 ,0xF7 ,0xE5 ,0x06 ,0x0A ,0x8C ,0xF2 ,0xF7 ,
    0xBA ,0x70 ,0xE6 ,0x24 ,0x42 ,0x5B ,0xD9 ,0x43 ,0xAA ,0xEE ,0x07 ,0x78 ,0x25 ,0xB9 ,0x18 ,0xBA ,
    0x11 ,0x92 ,0xA8 ,0x0C ,0xE8 ,0x89 ,0xD9 ,0x3C ,0xC7 ,0x4E ,0xF8 ,0x16 ,0x0B ,0x6C ,0xA1 ,0x2E ,
    0x39 ,0x1C ,0x8B ,0xED ,0xD9 ,0x11 ,0xE7 ,0xED ,0x2A ,0x1A ,0x31 ,0x25 ,0x25 ,0x8D ,0xD5 ,0x3A ,
    0x9B ,0x3C ,0x29 ,0x9E ,0xB0 ,0x51 ,0x98 ,0x6F ,0x25 ,0x8D ,0xBC ,0x9A ,0x55 ,0x96 ,0x51 ,0x15 ,
    0x1F ,0x1C ,0x91 ,0x5C ,0x25 ,0x55 ,0xD3 ,0x24 ,0xDA ,0xB5 ,0xD0 ,0xFA ,0xAA ,0x1C ,0x60 ,0x62 ,
    0x0A ,0x2D ,0xA9 ,0x83 ,0x78 ,0xDD ,0xDF ,0x5D ,0x71 ,0x13 ,0xF1 ,0x22 ,0x15 ,0x13 ,0x6C ,0x04 ,
    0x6C ,0x9A ,0xE4 ,0x4A ,0xB9 ,0x4C ,0xAF ,0xC7 ,0xD6 ,0xF6 ,0x11 ,0x6C ,0x4A ,0x9C ,0x5B ,0x65 ,
    0x78 ,0x6E ,0xA3 ,0x0A ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xDA ,0x41 ,0xA6 ,0x15 ,0x6B ,0x86 ,0xDE ,0x77 ,0xFF ,0xC2 ,
    0x13 ,0x50 ,0xD8 ,0x91 ,0x3E ,0xD2 ,0xF0 ,0xB1 ,0xC3 ,0x43 ,0x51 ,0x0B ,0xCD ,0x02 ,0x81 ,0x81 ,
    0x00 ,0xB6 ,0x40 ,0x45 ,0x5C ,0xB8 ,0x4D ,0x50 ,0x48 ,0xB7 ,0x0D ,0xA0 ,0x26 ,0x03 ,0xE3 ,0xFA ,
    0x3C ,0x2F ,0x04 ,0x9E ,0x72 ,0x1F ,0x1D ,0x30 ,0xEC ,0xEA ,0xF4 ,0xCE ,0x62 ,0xE6 ,0xE0 ,0xE7 ,
    0x3D ,0x3D ,0x03 ,0x68 ,0x3A ,0x90 ,0xE0 ,0xE3 ,0xB0 ,0x29 ,0x15 ,0x26 ,0x69 ,0xDE ,0xBB ,0x6E ,
    0x1A ,0xC2 ,0x5F ,0x5D ,0xB7 ,0x2B ,0x27 ,0x61 ,0x49 ,0x98 ,0x94 ,0x27 ,0x40 ,0x05 ,0x67 ,0xF3 ,
    0xC1 ,0x77 ,0x5B ,0x12 ,0x6D ,0x8D ,0x75 ,0xFA ,0x13 ,0x4D ,0x26 ,0x14 ,0x29 ,0x06 ,0x43 ,0xF8 ,
    0x3D ,0xB9 ,0x9F ,0x10 ,0x5E ,0xF9 ,0x30 ,0x79 ,0xF9 ,0x1B ,0x7D ,0x6A ,0x66 ,0x9F ,0xAA ,0x88 ,
    0x9F ,0x5E ,0x72 ,0xD4 ,0x3E ,0xE0 ,0xC0 ,0x04 ,0xC2 ,0xB2 ,0xD2 ,0xDF ,0x50 ,0xAB ,0x80 ,0xB9 ,
    0x5B ,0xF8 ,0x23 ,0x7D ,0x36 ,0xBD ,0x6F ,0xB2 ,0xFC ,0xF3 ,0x1F ,0x14 ,0xB9 ,0xC7 ,0xE9 ,0xAA ,
    0x25 ,0x02 ,0x81 ,0x81 ,0x00 ,0xBD ,0xCD ,0xBF ,0x79 ,0xD6 ,0x09 ,0x98 ,0xFA ,0xA2 ,0x7A ,0x93 ,
    0x65 ,0x5F ,0xDA ,0x40 ,0x42 ,0xFB ,0x79 ,0x23 ,0x0B ,0xBA ,0xCC ,0x35 ,0xA6 ,0x67 ,0xFB ,0x4F ,
    0xCF ,0x94 ,0x75 ,0xC8 ,0x30 ,0xDA ,0x1C ,0x69 ,0x1D ,0x87 ,0x1F ,0x35 ,0xF7 ,0x70 ,0x00 ,0xF6 ,
    0x50 ,0xD9 ,0x3C ,0xC7 ,0x57 ,0x25 ,0xA6 ,0xD6 ,0x04 ,0x87 ,0x99 ,0x4C ,0x16 ,0xED ,0x41 ,0x77 ,
    0x5D ,0x81 ,0xDD ,0x3A ,0x83 ,0xD3 ,0x89 ,0xB5 ,0xB7 ,0x99 ,0xB8 ,0x94 ,0x77 ,0x48 ,0x3D ,0xAB ,
    0xEB ,0xC6 ,0x19 ,0xAE ,0xF4 ,0x7A ,0x25 ,0x22 ,0xAD ,0xD0 ,0xB5 ,0x77 ,0x4A ,0xBA ,0xF0 ,0xA1 ,
    0x83 ,0xE2 ,0x35 ,0xFC ,0xBF ,0xE4 ,0xED ,0xBF ,0x68 ,0xF7 ,0xA8 ,0xA8 ,0x42 ,0xDF ,0x64 ,0xF3 ,
    0x87 ,0xB5 ,0x9D ,0x81 ,0x24 ,0x45 ,0x02 ,0x3D ,0x00 ,0xE6 ,0x88 ,0x20 ,0x2A ,0x46 ,0x8E ,0xE6 ,
    0xEF ,0xFC ,0xF7 ,0x5C ,0xCB ,0x02 ,0x81 ,0x81 ,0x00 ,0xAB ,0x87 ,0xC8 ,0xCF ,0xBC ,0x85 ,0x00 ,
    0x44 ,0x70 ,0x0C ,0xD2 ,0xF6 ,0x9A ,0x3F ,0xFA ,0x92 ,0xFF ,0x13 ,0x67 ,0xF2 ,0xF0 ,0x1B ,0x79 ,
    0x57 ,0x73 ,0xB9 ,0x3A ,0xB7 ,0x6F ,0xE2 ,0xBB ,0x84 ,0xEE ,0x21 ,0x53 ,0x09 ,0xF1 ,0xC4 ,0x9A ,
    0x0F ,0x35 ,0xB9 ,0x8D ,0x90 ,0xD1 ,0xA1 ,0x58 ,0x91 ,0xA7 ,0xE1 ,0x49 ,0x24 ,0xDD ,0x52 ,0x3D ,
    0x72 ,0x71 ,0x7C ,0x61 ,0x2D ,0x32 ,0x43 ,0xB8 ,0x3D ,0x9D ,0x82 ,0xE4 ,0x2A ,0xDF ,0x7E ,0x18 ,
    0x8A ,0xA2 ,0xF6 ,0xA9 ,0x90 ,0x05 ,0xE5 ,0x9E ,0x58 ,0x36 ,0x3B ,0x5A ,0xB3 ,0xBD ,0x5A ,0xCD ,
    0x26 ,0xB0 ,0x76 ,0x09 ,0xC9 ,0xFF ,0xAF ,0x8F ,0xA5 ,0x0D ,0x99 ,0x40 ,0x3B ,0x2D ,0xE1 ,0xE6 ,
    0x5C ,0xE4 ,0x8A ,0x3B ,0x97 ,0x38 ,0x00 ,0xAE ,0x74 ,0xAD ,0x4E ,0x93 ,0xF7 ,0x48 ,0xE1 ,0x99 ,
    0x66 ,0x8A ,0x77 ,0x9B ,0x09 ,0x34 ,0x9F ,0xAF ,0x31 ,0x02 ,0x81 ,0x80 ,0x6F ,0xA6 ,0x34 ,0x65 ,
    0xC9 ,0x32 ,0xD2 ,0x75 ,0x50 ,0x84 ,0x56 ,0xB4 ,0x1A ,0x44 ,0x25 ,0xCD ,0x0C ,0x65 ,0x5F ,0xE8 ,
    0xC8 ,0x3B ,0xE3 ,0x52 ,0xD3 ,0xC1 ,0x01 ,0xC5 ,0x66 ,0x63 ,0x66 ,0xB3 ,0x53 ,0x1F ,0xC5 ,0x5C ,
    0xA9 ,0xD6 ,0x1F ,0xBE ,0xBA ,0x5A ,0xEB ,0x3E ,0x9D ,0xE7 ,0x84 ,0x51 ,0x61 ,0x71 ,0x32 ,0x99 ,
    0x40 ,0xB4 ,0x87 ,0x1C ,0x8B ,0x8F ,0xEB ,0xDC ,0xA6 ,0xBE ,0x5E ,0xA7 ,0xE5 ,0xD8 ,0x89 ,0x02 ,
    0x96 ,0xA8 ,0xCF ,0xCD ,0xB2 ,0x06 ,0x28 ,0xE5 ,0x0B ,0x1E ,0x2A ,0xAD ,0xED ,0x7F ,0x41 ,0x93 ,
    0x6B ,0xB6 ,0x09 ,0xEF ,0xB9 ,0x42 ,0x40 ,0xE4 ,0x2A ,0xB6 ,0x58 ,0x70 ,0xE1 ,0x04 ,0x52 ,0x79 ,
    0xFB ,0x17 ,0xEA ,0x81 ,0xB0 ,0x95 ,0xBC ,0x6D ,0xF2 ,0x5C ,0xA6 ,0x51 ,0x92 ,0x01 ,0x51 ,0x0F ,
    0x96 ,0xAA ,0x6D ,0x46 ,0x0B ,0x63 ,0x1E ,0x6F ,0x0D ,0x46 ,0x36 ,0x95 ,0x02 ,0x81 ,0x80 ,0x41 ,
    0x3E ,0xA8 ,0x3B ,0x77 ,0xDC ,0xD7 ,0xAB ,0x2D ,0xD8 ,0x82 ,0x96 ,0x1C ,0x1B ,0x3B ,0xC6 ,0x85 ,
    0x92 ,0x88 ,0xAC ,0xC8 ,0xAC ,0x9F ,0x18 ,0x74 ,0x9D ,0x45 ,0xB4 ,0x7B ,0x13 ,0xAB ,0x78 ,0x8D ,
    0x8B ,0xB5 ,0x9E ,0x9E ,0xD2 ,0xD7 ,0xF2 ,0x84 ,0x34 ,0xFB ,0x08 ,0xB2 ,0x23 ,0xC7 ,0x0B ,0xF0 ,
    0xA9 ,0xCA ,0x17 ,0x1A ,0xA2 ,0x6D ,0x63 ,0xD3 ,0x90 ,0xEF ,0xD1 ,0x62 ,0xE6 ,0x46 ,0x25 ,0x6D ,
    0x6D ,0x23 ,0x3B ,0xB0 ,0x65 ,0xEA ,0xE2 ,0x22 ,0x24 ,0xC9 ,0x09 ,0x1B ,0x0D ,0x42 ,0x9D ,0x77 ,
    0xE1 ,0x63 ,0xB2 ,0x03 ,0x0D ,0x4A ,0xA2 ,0xFD ,0x2E ,0x2D ,0xCD ,0x4B ,0x9E ,0x63 ,0x91 ,0x0F ,
    0x42 ,0xC2 ,0x01 ,0x24 ,0x68 ,0x4C ,0xB5 ,0xA8 ,0x35 ,0xE3 ,0x31 ,0xE8 ,0x86 ,0x32 ,0xB1 ,0xA9 ,
    0x4F ,0xBE ,0x23 ,0x3A ,0x3C ,0x0A ,0x5D ,0x26 ,0xBE ,0xA7 ,0x5D ,0xC0 ,0x60 ,0x42 ,0x1D ,};


    for( int i =0; i<sizeof(szPrivateKey); i++ )
    {
        cout << szPrivateKey[i] << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope you threw away this key...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because there is an 0x07 (in the line starting with 0xBA) in the `szPrivateKey` - 0x07, or CTRL-G, on most systems, will be a `BEL` character, so it rings the bell on an old teletype. Modern computers, and even 30 year old terminals, don't have mechanical bells (nor do typewriters, if you can find one these days), so they use a beep instead.

In C and C++ you can make a BEL character in a string with `"\a"` (and it will work OK also on systems that aren't using ASCII, where it will generate whatever corresponding character is in a non-ASCII system).

By the way, this is not an "easter egg", it's the consequence of printing something that isn't really "text", so shouldn't be displayed with `cout`. You can get the same with `type myfile.dat` or something like that (assuming `myfile.dat` is a binary file and has a 0x07 byte in it).

Comment: Printing random binary on an old ASR33 TTY was always quite a show -- the type wheel would spin violently and the bell would ring and the platen would keep advancing.  (Though surprisingly few carriage returns in random binary -- it would tend to run out to the right margin and sit there, creating a smudge down the right-hand side of the page.)

Comment: It was always "fun" when someone accidentally printed a binary on the big printers we had at school and early work places - and yes, it seems to be more linefeeds and page-feeds in there than carriage returns for some reason/

Answer (score 20):

Character `0x07` is the ASCII bell character. Support varies, but sending it to a console generally results in a single beep noise.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the first 10 entries of the ascii table:

```
   Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        
   ---------------------------------------------
   000   0     00    NUL '\0'                
   001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)  
   002   2     02    STX (start of text)     
   003   3     03    ETX (end of text)       
   004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)
   005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)           
   006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)       
   007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)         
   010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)    
   011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)
```

Notice the ascii code 7 , many terminals will perform an audible sound if you write that character to it.

Comment: oh interesting, damn, using C++ for almost 3 years now and there's still surprises in it! will accept as soon as S.O allows

Comment: @Viniyo Shouta: This has nothing to do with C++. This is about specific properties of specific output devices.

Answer (score 4):

`\a`, also known as `BEL`, has a vlue of `0x07` in most machines.

From C++11 2.14.3

> alert BEL \a

From C99 5.2.2

> \a(alert) Produces an audible or visible alert without changing the active position.

Comment: `0x0B` is vertical tab.